# Unity Doesn't Load On 14.04

Tags: unity, compiz

I have already tried many different solutions. Running `unity` from `tty1` does not make unity appear int `tty7` (the graphics one). Running `unity` from a terminal inside of `tty7` causes the screen to flash until eventually turning black. I have the Unity plugin enabled in `ccsm`.

I keep on getting an error about `could not connect: connection refused`.

I do not have a `/org/compiz` that is metion in the command `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`.

I did not update Ubuntu or anything, I've been running 14.04 for months. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: @wolf None of the solutions worked for me.